# Investing in cryptocurrency in India

Tags: wallet

Question: My friend in India wants to start investing in cryptocurrency such as bitcoin. I have a few questions. What is the current legality of cryptocurrency in India? What exchange should he use? What wallet app should he use (should support main popular coins)?

Answer (score -1):

Crypto was declared legal in India, earlier this year by the Supreme Court. That being said there are no legal frameworks/regulations right now by the government.

WazirX is one popular exchange in India. Haven't used it though.

Comment: None of the KYC exchanges in India are good

Comment: mentioned that haven't used it, therefore got no idea.